# Printing A Data Inside A Modal

Tags: php, mysql

When I hit the View button, that modal will pop-up. The modal contains details to be printed. Can you please help what should I do with it? Thank you in advance.

[This will be the pop-up modal when I hit the view button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM7ee.png)

The code below was used for the view button:

```
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Work Request</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="request_detail">  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </div>
```

And the script for the View Button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
       var request_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       if(request_id != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"select.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{request_id:request_id},  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#request_detail').html(data);  
                      $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                 }  
            });  
       }            
  });
```

This one is for the Print button:

```
<script>
 $().ready(function () {
    $('.modal.printable').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       $('.modal-dialog', this).addClass('focused');
       $('body').addClass('modalprinter');

    if ($(this).hasClass('autoprint')) {
        window.print();
    }
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal-dialog', this).removeClass('focused');
    $('body').removeClass('modalprinter');
   });
});
```

When I hit the Print the button, it's working but, (just look at the photo): [This is the result of clicking the Print button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Mfn.png)

Comment: have you tried anything. maybe some code?

Comment: prepopulate the modal before viewing it, or use js

Comment: @AgamBanga Thank you for your response. I have tried a code, but it prints all the request, I want to print one request at a time

Comment: @AgamBanga I hope you'll find time looking on what I've changed in my question.